# KQL how able to slice the data in smaller chunks

Tags: azure, kql, azure-resource-graph

I have this query but the output returns 106K records, what I need to add to the query do smaller chunks for data extract and export on CSV.

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend
            JoinID = toupper(id),
            VMName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName),
            OSType = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType),
            VMSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize),
OSVersion = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.osVersion),
OSName = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.osName)
| join kind=leftouter(
            Resources
            | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions'
            | extend 
                            VMId = toupper(substring(id, 0, indexof(id, '/extensions'))),
                            ExtensionType = properties.type,
    ExtensionPublisher = properties.publisher
    ) on $left.JoinID == $right.VMId
```

does azure graph explorer or kql has any data export data limitation?

### I have modified the query per suggestion and works for me.

```
   Resources
    | where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
    | extend
            JoinID = toupper(id),
            VMName = tostring(properties.osProfile.computerName),
            OSType = tostring(properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType),
            VMSize = tostring(properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize),
    OSVersion = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.osVersion),
    OSName = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.osName)
    | join kind=leftouter(
           Resources
            | where type == 
    'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions'
            | extend 
                            VMId = toupper(substring(id, 0, indexof(id, 
     '/extensions'))),
                            ExtensionPublisher = properties.publisher,
                            Extension_Publisher  = 
      tostring(properties.publisher),
                            ExtensionType =  properties.type
      ) on $left.JoinID == $right.VMId
      | project-away  identity1, kind, managedBy, sku, identity, 
       zones,extendedLocation,extendedLocation1, kind1, managedBy1, 
      sku1, tags1, zones1, systemData1,tags,
      systemData, tenantId, JoinID, id1, id, VMName, location1, 
      tenantId1, OSType, type1, apiVersion1, VMId,  apiVersion, plan1,
```

ExtensionPublisher
| sort by Extension_Publisher asc
| extend row_number = row_number()
| where row_number > 0
| take 200

Comment: What's stopping you from exporting 106k records?

Comment: -   I can only export 55K rows to a csv file not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend a row number and filter by that field to paginate (offset), then you take (or limit) the amount of records you want.

```
Resources
  ...
  | serialize 
  | extend row_number = row_number()
  | where row_number > 10000
  | take 5000
```

This query returns 5000 records from 10001 to 15000.

Edit:

As @david-דודו-markovitz remarked in comments, queries should be consistent between calls. So you should prepare the main query (the elipses part) with an order by clausule and ensure you retrieve the same records even if the data source changes over time, for example, with a where between times.

Comment: Brave move, using row_number without a defined order and trust the rows to appear in the same order in each run

Comment: Of course, the query should be idempotent to works well. Not only ensure the order, but also the number of results, perhaps through a Where by date. The main query must go in the ellipses.

Comment: Quick remark - after `order by`, no need for `serialize `

Comment: I have added the modified query at the bottom of the initial question works for me probably help others.